# Can an included use case be associated to an actor?

Tags: uml, use-case

Use case diagram where an actor is associated to an included use case:

[image]

Could I do something like this?

Comment: I agree that the arrow must be open (didn't see it when making the diagram).
However, why should the relationship be an extend?

Comment: Uhm. Now my bad. Include, of course. They always come in packs..

Comment: Hello Nightcore, are you satisfied with my answer? If yes, please mark it as accepted (green check mark), otherwise please explain what you still need.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I have one more question: Could the above use cases be associated with the SAME actor? Thank you for your answer (I have just marked it!)

Comment: Yes, it can....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that is allowed. For example, an actor's goal can be finding product info (without the intention to buy it) and that actor will do use case 'Find product', whereas for another actor, that is just the first step towards buying. Use case 'Buy product' includes 'Find product' and both are associated with an actor.

By the way, the arrow in your diagram should have an open arrowhead and the word 'include' should be written between guillemets.